# Rock, Paper, Scissors style game (Cowboy, Ninja, Bear)

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

In our assignment found [**here**](http://www.cs.uni.edu/~diesburg/courses/cs1510_sp15/homework/PA05/index.htm) we are creating a game called Cowboy, Ninja, Bear which is essentially Rock, Paper, Scissors. So I have two questions.

1.) How do I assign c, n, or b to the random number generated by the program of 1, 2, or 3?

2.) Is there a quick and easy way to make sure that N is equal to n in order to shorten the code when comparing the program's choice and the user's choice? So it only has to compare between c, b, and n instead of throwing C, B, and N into the loop as well?

```
"""
Author: 
Program: cnb.py
Description: A game of Cowboy, Ninja, Bear. Similar to Rock, Paper, Scissors.
The user picks either Ninja, Cowboy, or Bear. The program compares this against
its own randomly generated choice and replys with the rounds outcome. The program
also keeps track of the number of wins, losses, ties, and overall rounds.
"""

import random
random.seed()

counter = 1
winCounter = 0
loseCounter = 0
tieCounter = 0

#Input Rules

print ("Enter:")
print ("  'C' or 'c' for Cowboy")
print ("  'N' or 'n' for Ninja")
print ("  'B' or 'b' for Bear")
print()


#Prompt user for input

print ("Round", counter, "Fight!")
userStr = input("Please enter a weapon: ")



#If user input is not compliant with rules instruct
#user to retry.

if userStr == "q" or userStr == "Q":
    print("Game Over!")
if userStr != "N" or userStr != "n" or userStr != "C" or userStr != "c" or userStr != "B" or userStr != "b" or userStr == "q" or userStr == "Q":
    print ()
    print ("That's not a valid choice!")
    userStr = input("Please enter a weapon: ")

#Computer picks Weapon

computer = random.randint(1,3)



#Compare Results and print results

#Win
if userStr == c and computer == c
    winCounter = winCounter + 1
    print ("You win")
if userStr == n and computer == n
    winCounter = winCounter + 1
    print ("You win")
if userStr == b and computer == b
    winCounter = winCounter + 1
    print ("You win")

#Loss
if userStr == c and computer == c
    lossCounter = lossCounter + 1
    print ("You lose")
if userStr == n and computer == n
    lossCounter = lossCounter + 1
    print ("You lose")
if userStr == b and computer == b
    lossCounter = lossCounter + 1
    print ("You lose")

#Tie
if userStr == c and computer == c
    tieCounter = tieCounter + 1
    print ("You tied")
if userStr == n and computer == n
    tieCounter = tieCounter + 1
    print ("You tied")
if userStr == b and computer == b
    tieCounter = tieCounter + 1
    print ("You tied")



#Loop to new round

counter = counter + 1
print()
print ("Round", counter)
userStr = input("Please enter a weapon: ")
```

Comment: quick note. This is always True: `if userStr != "N" or userStr != "n" or userStr != "C" or userStr != "c" or userStr != "B" or userStr != "b" or userStr == "q" or userStr == "Q":
`

Comment: for 1) instead of generating a number, choose from a list. ie `foo = ['c', 'b', 'n']
print(random.choice(foo))`

Comment: for 2) convert the user input to lowercase, ie `s.lower()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To assign one of the three letters at random, don't bother going through an integer -- just assign one of the three letters at random!

```
computer = random.choice('cnb')
```

However, you have other bugs in your code, e.g

```
if userStr != "N" or userStr != "n" or (etc etc)
```

`userStr` will **always** be different from `'N'` or different from `'n'` (etc) -- after all, if it equals one, it can't also equal the other, no?!

So here you must use `and`, **not** `or`...!-)

As for normalizing upper/lower case, just do:

```
userStr = userStr.lower()
```

and it will always be lowercase.

Comment: Thank you so much! As for the and vs or I don't know how I missed that when typing it out. That is one I should have caught. Thank you again though this answer was very helpful!

Comment: With the computer = random.choice('cnb') line I am getting this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/cnb.py", line 47, in <module>
    computer = random.randint("cnb")
TypeError: randint() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'

Comment: @Kryx: not `randint`, but `choice`.

Comment: @Kryx, exactly as Ethan says: you say `with random.choice` but the error message unambiguously tells us that's definitely **not** what you're using -- instead, you're still calling `randint`, which stands for "random integer", when you absolutely **don't** want an **integer** at all?!

Comment: No I had changed it to random.choice('cnb') in my own code and got that exact error before I asked about it wondering if there was a typo or I was missing some small detail. However I did find the error myself so no worries. Thank you Mr. Martelli for getting me started in the right direction.